# NetworkX g.neighbors(n) time complexity

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

What is the time complexity of getting the neighbors of a node in networkx?

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edges_from([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')])
>>> G.neighbors('a')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: obtaining the neighbors takes *linear* time *O(m)* (with *m* the number neighbors, or in unlikely scenarios *O(m+n)* with *n* the number of nodes). Adding edges to the network will normally take *linear* time as well *O(n)* in the *number* of edges that you add, so constant for a single edge, but in a (very) unlikely scenario could take quadratic time *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. You can access the dictionary of neighbors in *constant time* (well in a worst case scenario linear time) with `G['a'].

We can inspect the [source code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/classes/graph.html#Graph.neighbors), and see:

> ```
> def neighbors(self, n):
>     # ...
>     try:
>         return list(self.adj[n])
>     except KeyError:
>         raise NetworkXError("The node %s is not in the graph." % (n,))
> ```

Now if inspect the source code, we see that (by *default*) `adj` is a dictionary, indeed:

> ```
> node_dict_factory = dict
> adjlist_dict_factory = dict
> edge_attr_dict_factory = dict
>
> def __init__(self, data=None, **attr):
>     # ...
>     self.node_dict_factory = ndf = self.node_dict_factory
>     # ...
>     self.node = ndf()  # empty node attribute dict
>     # ...
> ```

So even if the dictionary lookup takes - worst case, but very unlikely - linear time *O(n)* in the number of nodes, then we only have another linear time to convert the list of keys into a list.

The `add_edges_from` method on the other hand is implemented as:

> ```
> def add_edges_from(self, ebunch, attr_dict=None, **attr):
>     # ...
>     for e in ebunch:
>         ne = len(e)
>         if ne == 3:
>             u, v, dd = e
>         elif ne == 2:
>             u, v = e
>             dd = {}  # doesnt need edge_attr_dict_factory
>         else:
>             raise NetworkXError(
>                 "Edge tuple %s must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple." % (e,))
>         if u not in self.node:
>             self.adj[u] = self.adjlist_dict_factory()
>             self.node[u] = {}
>         if v not in self.node:
>             self.adj[v] = self.adjlist_dict_factory()
>             self.node[v] = {}
>         datadict = self.adj[u].get(v, self.edge_attr_dict_factory())
>         datadict.update(attr_dict)
>         datadict.update(dd)
>         self.adj[u][v] = datadict
>         self.adj[v][u] = datadict
> ```

So we basically iterate over every item in the list, do some unpacking, and then add the data dictionary twice to the `adj` (once in one direction, once in the other). If the dictionary lookup is fast (usually it is constant time), then this algorithm has *linear time* (in the number of tuples to add). Worst case (but very unlikely) dictionary lookups can take linear time, so then inserting can scale up to *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

The `Graph` class however allows access to the subdictionary with `G['a']`:

```
>>> G['a']
AtlasView({'b': {}, 'c': {}})
```

The `AtlasView` is a view over the dictionary to prevent one from *editing* the underlying dictionary.

Comment: thanks! so if i want to do many fast neighbor lookups in an unchanging graph, I suppose it would be better pre-process and store the neighbors of every node in a dictionary {node: {neighbors}} ?

Comment: @CarlosG.Oliver: you can use `G['a']`, this will return you the *subdictionary* of that node, and the keys thus contain the neighbours. This will thus (under normal circumstances) give you the dictionary in constant time. Note however then you here got access to the "data" of the graph, and changing the dictionary will have effect on your graph `G`.

Comment: @CarlosG.Oliver  I wouldn't advise this preprocessing.  I don't think any speedup from having your dictionary structure over the underlying dictionary structure in networkx would make up for the time it takes to do the preprocessing (in fact, I don't see why your dictionary would be any faster than networkx's).  You also double the memory footprint, and introduce the possibility of a bug.